# Add latency and random packet drops excluding SSH packets

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, redhat, tc

I want to add some random delay/drop to all packets excluding **SSH** packets.

I can do that to all packets this way:

```
tc qdisc change dev $NIC root netem delay 100ms 10ms 25%
tc qdisc change dev $NIC root netem loss 10% 25%
```

And I can mark SSH packets using **iptables** this way:

```
iptables -N TOP
iptables -I OUTPUT -j TOP
iptables -A TOP -p tcp --dport 22 -j RETURN
iptables -A TOP -p tcp --sport 22 -j RETURN
iptables -A TOP -j MARK --set-mark 9

service iptables save
```

But I don't know how to combine them? I mean I can't find a way to apply the delay/drop to all packets **excluding the marked ones**!

Answer (score 2):

You can only really apply QoS to outbound traffic, as you have no control over what's being sent to you. So adding rules to the INPUT chain as you do isn't going to end well.

You can use the CLASSIFY target in the POSTROUTING chain of the mangle table to classify packets for tc to work on.

> CLASSIFY
>
> This module allows you to set the skb->priority value (and thus classify the packet into a specific CBQ class).
>
> --set-class major:minor
> Set the major and minor class value. The values are always interpreted as hexadecimal even if no 0x prefix is given.

The major:minor classid is what you use in tc to handle the traffic. If you classify some specific traffic as say classid 10:201 then in tc you create a parent 10:200 and add the 10:201 class to that.

Note that to add rules to the POSTROUTING chain you have to explicitly use the mangle table

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 --set-class 100:22 -j CLASSIFY
```

Comment: and how to apply this class in my tc commands? can you give example?

Comment: No. I don't like to give examples without testing them and I don't have the time to do that with this. Also, you need the education more than I do. You clearly haven't done much research (cf INPUT for QoS). Now I have pointed you in the right direction you should be able to get a long way and perhaps all the way to a solution with some personal research and a lab. Believe it or not this will be much better for you than me doing it and feeding you an answer. Now you know what to look for you should be able to use your google-fu to move forward.

Comment: Of course it will be good for me, and I love it, but I don't have enough time now

Comment: If you don't have enough time now you never will.